# Post checkbox, what value to put?

Tags: html, node.js

I'm using NodeJs to post login on a page that has this form:

```
<form method="post" action="/user/account/login/">
    <div id=loginform>
        <label class="field-title">Username </label><label class="txt-field"><input name="username" type="text" tabindex="1" /></label>
        <label class="field-title">Password </label><label class="txt-field"><input name="password" type="password" tabindex="2"/></label>
    </div>
    <div id="remember">
        Remember Me: <input name="remember_me" type="checkbox" tabindex="3" />
       <input name="login" type="submit" value="submit" tabindex="4"/><br>
   </div>
</form>
```

I can post this:

```
credentials = {
    username: 'myusername',
    password: 'mypass'
};
```

And log in successfully. But how to I check the `remember_me` box? What value should it have? Something like this: `remember_me: 'true'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the checkbox is checked, then it's value will be whatever the `value` attribute says. If you fail to provide one, it will be `"on"`.

If the checkbox is not checked, then it won't be a successful control and won't appear in form data at all.

See [Constructing the form data set](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-form-data-set).

Comment: The checkbox does not have a `value` attribute, so it will be `"on"` if checked?